# Using Automatic Image montage with Jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, montage

I am using the automatic image montage plugin found here:

http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/index4.html

I am using Jquery to call my additional images upon the click of a button.

```
<div id="montage_overlay" class="paddingspacer2">
                <div class="am-container" id="am-container">

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_181.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="'92 Bison Alumni"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_181.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_183.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Alumni Honored"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_183.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_185.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Yuker at Bubba's"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_185.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_186.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Home Team for 3"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_186.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_188.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="...the crowd gets the skinny on W&J"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_188.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_189.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Finish Regular Season in Strong Fashion"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_189.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_190.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="...a long weekend in b-town"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_190.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02282008_192.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Baller #1"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02282008_192.jpg"></img></a>

                </div>
                <div id="loadmore2" class="siteusemorebox">
                    <a href="#" class="loadmore" id="2">View more media</a>
                </div>              
            </div>

            <div class="clearboth"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/plugins/montage/jquery.montage.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript1.1">
                window.media_more_script = '/ajax_results.cfm?rpp=6&ajax_type=my_group_photos&eventid=37&media_type=1&myscript=%2Findex%2Ecfm%2Fleague%2F23%2Faction%2Fdashboard%2Fcontent%5Faction%2Fevents%2Feventid%2F37%2Fevent%5Faction%2Fphotos';
            </script>                       
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    var $container  = $('#am-container'),
                        $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide(),
                        totalImgs   = $imgs.length,
                        cnt         = 0;

                    $imgs.each(function(i) {
                        var $img    = $(this);
                        $('<img/>').load(function() {
                            ++cnt;
                            if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
                                $imgs.show();
                                $container.montage({
                                    minw : 150,
                                    alternateHeight : true,
                                    alternateHeightRange : {
                                        min : 150,
                                        max : 350
                                    },
                                    margin : 3,
                                    fillLastRow : true
                                });

                                /* 
                                 * just for this demo:
                                 */
                                $('#montage_overlay').fadeIn(500);

                                $(document).on("click",'.loadmore',function()                               
                                    {
                                    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
                                    var myscript3 = window.media_more_script || null;                       
                                    if(ID)
                                        {
                                        $("#loadmore"+ID).html('<img src="/images/processing.gif" />');                 
                                        $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: myscript3,
                                        data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
                                        cache: false,
                                        success: function(html){$container.append(html).montage( 'add',html);}
                                        });
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                        $(".siteusemorebox").html('No more records.');
                                        }               
                                    return false;
                                }); 


                            }
                        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                    }); 

                });
            </script>
```

Google Chrome returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Object 
                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02282008_192.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Baller #1"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02282008_192.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_190.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="...a long weekend in b-town"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_190.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_189.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Finish Regular Season in Strong Fashion"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_189.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_188.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="...the crowd gets the skinny on W&J"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_188.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_186.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Home Team for 3"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_186.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_185.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Yuker at Bubba's"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_185.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_183.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="Bison Alumni Honored"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_183.jpg"></img></a>

                        <a href="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_181.jpg" rel="galleryfacebox" title="'92 Bison Alumni"><img src="http://mediastorage.playerspace.com/photo/groups/6_02252008_181.jpg"></img></a>
                     has no method 'find' [http://halosummerleague.playerspace.com/scripts/jquery/plugins/montage/jquery.montage.min.js:1]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

got it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $container  = $('##am-container'),
                $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide(),
                totalImgs   = $imgs.length,
                cnt         = 0;

            $imgs.each(function(i) {
                var $img    = $(this);
                $('<img/>').load(function() {
                    ++cnt;
                    if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
                        $imgs.show();
                        $container.montage({
                            minw : 150,
                            alternateHeight : true,
                            alternateHeightRange : {
                                min : 150,
                                max : 350
                            },
                            margin : 3,
                            fillLastRow : true
                        });
                        $('##montage_overlay').fadeIn(500);                             
                        $(document).on("click",'.loadmore',function()                               
                            {
                            var ID = $(this).attr("id");
                            var myscript3 = window.media_more_script || null;                       
                            if(ID)
                                {
                                    $("##loadmore"+ID).html('<img src="/images/processing.gif" />');                    
                                    $.ajax
                                        ({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: myscript3,
                                            data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
                                            cache: false,
                                            success: function(html){

                                                var $newimages = $( html );
                                                $newimages.imagesLoaded( function(){
                                                $container.append( $newimages ).montage( 'add', $newimages );
                                                $("##loadmore"+ID).remove();
                                                });                                                 
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    $(".siteusemorebox").html('No more records.');
                                    $("##loadmore"+ID).remove();
                                }               
                            return false;
                        });                 
                    }
                }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
            }); 

        });
    </script>
```